# I get a unknown column error but I do have the column?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, relational-database

So I am making my first RESTful API in java and I am stuck.
I am using foreign keys, so I came across ORM.
I am learning about it so I don't understand everything probably.
Anyway I am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user0_.account_id' in 'field list'
```

While I think I do have that column.

**MY DATABASE (the relevant part of it):**

[image: database model]

**My User model class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    public User(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="accountId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    private Account account;


    public User(){

    }

}
```

**My Account model class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account {

    public Account(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, Boolean locked, Boolean enabled) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Boolean locked;
    private Boolean enabled;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private User user;

    public Account(){

    }


}
```

I can't seem to find an answer that works for me in other similar posts.
I do think it has something to do with mapping but I am not sure.
I think you only need these 2 classes, but if you need to have anything else to answer my question, please ask them and I will include them in my post.

Thanks in advance!

To make my database more clear I have added the database tab from IntelliJ so that you can see how the columns are named:

[image: database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by feedback from my teacher. I have implemented the user and account tables the wrong way around.
I needed to implement it in this way:
[image: database]

When I changed this in my database and in my code like this:

**User class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    public User(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Account account;


    public User(){

    }
```

**Account class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account {

    public Account(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, Boolean locked, Boolean enabled) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.locked = locked;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Boolean locked;
    private Boolean enabled;



    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    public Account(){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this in your class `User`:

```
@JoinColumn(name="accountId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
private Account account;
```

You have to use database column names here, not entity field names. If the column is really named `account_id` in the database (as seems to be the case from the error message), then this should be:

```
@JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Account account;
```

Comment: When I try to do this I get an error in IntelliJ which says: Cannot resolve column 'account_id'
When I type accountId I do not get this error. Next to that the referencedColumnName with or without capital I gives the same error (just tried it).

Comment: I added the database to the post